# How do I make the text appear after 3barplot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why doesn't zorder work in this case? I've tried using it but the text still ends up being covered by the bar plot towers.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Percentage_Differences_1 = np.array([ [7.94*(10**-10),7.94*(10**-9),7.94*(10**-8),7.94*(10**-7),7.94*(10**-6),7.94*(10**-5)],
                                [7.92*(10**-12),7.92*(10**-11),7.92*(10**-10),7.92*(10**-9),7.92*(10**-8),7.92*(10**-7)],
                                [7.72*(10**-14),7.72*(10**-13),7.72*(10**-12),7.72*(10**-11),7.72*(10**-10),7.72*(10**-9)],
                                [5.66*(10**-16),5.66*(10**-15),5.66*(10**-14),5.66*(10**-13),5.66*(10**-12),5.66*(10**-11)],
                                [1.49*(10**-17),1.49*(10**-16),1.49*(10**-15),1.49*(10**-14),1.49*(10**-13),1.49*(10**-12)],
                                [2.21*(10**-18),2.21*(10**-17),2.21*(10**-16),2.21*(10**-15),2.21*(10**-14),2.21*(10**-13)] ]) # Layer 1, 12

fig1 = plt.figure(dpi = 120, tight_layout = True)
fig1.set_size_inches(10, 7)

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

width = depth = 0.3

column_names = ['$10^{-6} m$','$10^{-5} m$','$10^{-4} m$','$10^{-3} m$','$10^{-2} m$','$10^{-1} m$']
row_names = ['$10^{-6} g$','$10^{-5} g$','$10^{-4} g$','$10^{-3} g$','$10^{-2} g$','$10^{-1} g$']
height_names = ['$10^{-2}$','$10^{-4}$','$10^{-6}$','$10^{-8}$','$10^{-10}$','$10^{-12}$','$10^{-14}$','$10^{-16}$','$10^{-18}$']

for x in range(0,6):
    for y in range(0,6):
        plot1 = ax1.bar3d(x, y, 0, width, depth, np.log10(Percentage_Differences_1[x][y]), color = "#0040bf", alpha=0.3, zorder = 1)
        txt1 = ax1.text(x,y,1.15*np.log10(Percentage_Differences_1[x][y]),'{:.2e}'.format(Percentage_Differences_1[y][x]), verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5), zorder = 2)
        
ax1.view_init(-140, -30)

ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 6, num = 6))
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, 6, num = 6))
ax1.set_xticklabels(column_names)
ax1.set_yticklabels(row_names)
ax1.set_zticklabels(height_names)
ax1.set_xlabel("Mass", labelpad = 13, rotation = 45)
ax1.set_ylabel("Radius", labelpad = 10, rotation = 45)
ax1.set_zlabel("Deviation $\Delta$")
ax1.set_title("1st Initial Condition: $r(0)$ and $r'(0)$ of $\Theta(12) = 2.18 \\times 10^{7} m$", pad = 40)

plt.show()
```

I've tried using both set_zorder and zorder but the plot still ends up covering the majority of the text labels.

[image: 3d Bar Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Change your `zorder` for a number larger than the number of bar objects, 100 for example:
[image]